# how to redirect www.sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, redirect

how to redirect www.sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com?

other info:

1. right now sub.domain.com works, www.sub.domain.com is 'server not
   found'.
2. im using drupal 6. I dont want to add an A record because the caching module i use (Boost) will cache a version of the site with www and without www, effectively doubling the cache size. <-- Not really sure about that but that's the case with my site at its previous host. In any case this is probably just a simple htaccess issue.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this helps, inside .htaccess file?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Also: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-keep-domain-consistency-with-or-without-www/50553#50553